# Ball trapped without entering the hole

Tags: rules, golf

[image]

What rule should I apply in a situation like this. I know i very uncommon, but I should not touch the ball. Could be the plastic be considered a mobile obstruction? The ball is clearly inside the hole.

Comment: How does something like this even happen?!!

Comment: The plastic to support the border was broken. Don't have any idea how. It wasn't my problem either. Just looking for a solution..

Comment: Hilarious and bad luck. Never seen this happen before

Comment: Reason # 123494 why those cup liners should never be used!  They are illegal to boot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying [Decision 16/2](http://www.usga.org/rules/rules-and-decisions.html#!decision-16) from the USGA Rules of Golf, this is considered holed (although it doesn't fit the definition of holed).

---

> **16/2 Ball Embedded in Side of Hole; All of Ball Below Lip of Hole**
>
> Q.A player's ball embeds in the side of a hole. All of the ball is below
>   the level of the lip of the hole. What is the ruling?
>
> A.The ball should be considered holed even though all of the ball is
>   not within the circumference of the hole as required by the Definition
>   of "Holed."

Definition of "Holed":

> A ball is "holed" when it is at rest within the circumference of the
>   hole and all of it is below the level of the lip of the hole.